# Why West Virginia is one of the least-vaccinated states in the country due to cash giveaway announcement?

Tags: monetary-policy, united-states, covid-19-crisis

In a [newspaper](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/covid-vaccine-incentives/2021/08/08/f586d3c6-f5ec-11eb-a636-18cac59a98dc_story.html), I saw the paragraph

> In some U.S. states that held lotteries for vaccine recipients, with
> some prizes reaching the million-dollar mark, leaders reported upticks
> in interest, but it’s unclear how large of a role the incentive
> played. **West Virginia, among the first to announce cash giveaways,
> remains one of the least-vaccinated states in the country**.

Even in some paper,the monetary incentives is not really a good way to persuade the people to vaccinate [(Sprengholz 2021, page 1)](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/8959e2b4-0587-382a-a8ac-ebac86c104c5/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B1ad846af-3cdb-3ba3-b23d-9715ee04810b%7D). However, in West Virginia, it **even becomes the least-vaccinated states in US**, I am wondering what is the logical explanation behind this phenomenon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why West Virginia is the least vaccinated state* in the US but

1. If vaccination is progressing poorly in your state the government is more likely to try and encourage it by all sorts of measures - like vaccine lotteries/cash giveaways. Thus it is not the giveaways that cause low vaccination rates, but rather the other way around.
2. There has to be a least vaccinated state.

If you combine 1. and 2. you will see that it is likely that the least vaccinated state will have a cash giveaway program (or something similar).

---

*In fact, [Alabama seems to be the currently least vaccinated state](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2020/health/covid-vaccine-states-distribution-doses/).

Comment: +1 I would just add for the sake of OP, that this is classic example of endogeneity/reverse causality, so indeed one can’t make inferences here just by correlating monetary incentives with vaccination